# Render handlebars script inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to render a handlebars script inside a `div`. This used to work fine with *ember.0.9.8.js*, but now that I'm using *ember-1.0.0-pre.2.js* and *handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js* it doesn't work any more. The rendered script is put outside the `div`.

Here is a JSFiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YnwQB/

Here is the same thing with ember 9.8, which works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zWGyn/

Is this a bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answser my own question based on some comment on the Ember.js [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1552#issuecomment-10541095) I reported:

I have to use `data-template-name="application"` and `rootElment` in the `Ember.Application`. Here is the jsfiddle that solves it: http://jsfiddle.net/YnwQB/5/